# Is it possible to compare the current time with a custom "start" and "end date

Tags: custom-field, meta-query

I need to be able to display a custom post type if the current date is between the start and end custom meta field dates. Here is my code so far, it seems to just be ignoring the query and displaying all 3 of the posts, I have probably made a mistake as I have been been working on it for 3 days straight now, any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not even sure if this can work, I have successfully been able to show the posts that are after the end date and posts before the start date but can seem to get the ones that are between the two dates.

```
    $todaysDate = date('Y/m/d');
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'exhibitions',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'meta_query' => array(

    array('key' => 'start_date', 'value' => $todaysDate, 'compare' => '>=', 'type' => 'DATE'),
    array('key' => 'end_date', 'value' => $todaysDate, 'compare' => '<=', 'type' => 'DATE') 
) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested solution, just a thought really, but what if `'value' => 'NOW()'` so that you avoid having to pass the date, which seems like it's probably the issue?

## EDIT

Alternate solution: Your SQL date format is wrong. It should be `$todaysDate = date( 'Y-m-d' )`, that should also be the format it is stored in if the row format is `DATE` or `TIME`